# Django: ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'

Tags: python, django, celery

So I've installed `celery` and got the file `celery_tasks_settings.py` in my project directory next to `settings.py`. This I got was a way to avoid conflicts with the package itself.

I also did

```sh
find -name '*celery*.pyc'
```

as a way to find any `celery.pyc` files that may have been generated before.The result:

```sh
/__pycache__/celery_tasks.cpython-38.pyc
/__pycache__/celery_tasks_settings.cpython-38.pyc
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same error:

```sh
   from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I also went ahead and tried adding:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

to my `celery_tasks_settings.py`

My error still won't budge.
[EDIT] 
Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/HotelManagement/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .celery_tasks_settings import app as celery_app
  File "/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/HotelManagement/celery_tasks_settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery' (/run/media/marvin/DriveEtCetera/Python/MyProjectsDirectory/super-lamp/.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__init__.py)
```

Comment: What does

`import celery` `print celery.__file__`

say?

Comment: `.superlamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__init__.py` .Which would be under my virtual env called `.superlamp`

Comment: And what about `import celery; celery.__dict__`?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: @h3yduck  the dictionary is too long for the comment section.It starts as this though `'__name__': 'celery', '__doc__': 'Distributed Task Queue.', '__package__': 'celery',`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I upgraded importlib-metadata from verion 0.19 to version 1.5.0 and it totally resolved this issue for me.

For reference, I had an almost identical full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/voiceover_backend/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/voiceover_backend/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery' (/mnt/SSD/uvo/help/voiceover_backend/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__init__.py)
```

It got totally fixed when I upgraded importlib-metadata.

```
pip install --upgrade importlib-metadata
```

Comment: You, my friend, deserve a round on me. `pip install --upgrade importlib-metadata
` does the charm.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for this! I actually had the exact opposite problem: my installed copy of `importlib-metadata` was too *new*, and that was breaking the celery import. Downgrading from 5.0.0 to 4.13.0 fixed it. I'm using Python 3.7 in this docker image, which may be related.

Comment: Same here! Took me too long to figure this out, so I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74136587/10180115 importlib-metadata version 5 and celery break on specific Python versions (in my case Python 3.7).

Answer (score 1):

Posted this answer on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011159/importerror-cannot-import-name-celery), but it actually suits better here. So again:
I recently upgraded from Python 3.6 to **Python 3.7** and I am using **Celery 4.4.6** and **Django 2.2.x** and it also gave me a similar error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'
```

However, as I had my project setup as told in the [docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.4.6/django/first-steps-with-django.html) it was referring to the right package. Only after some lost hours I stumbled accross this [Issue](https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/issues/411) here. I then fixed

```
importlib-metadata==4.8.3
```

and the problem was resolved. According to GitHub all versions < 5 might resolve the issue. Apparently Celery uses an interface from this package on specific Python versions, which they deprecated in version 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a circular import issue.  It looks like you are trying to import `Celery` in the celery_task_settings.py and that is causing a circular import leading to the import error.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that's how one should work with `celery`. Importing the module in a file and only then importing your file in the project's init so celery can work

Comment: If you want help with the circular import, please post your celery_task_settings.py, celery.py, and django settings files.

Comment: `celery.py` would be the standard package. My celery_task_settings file, however, has been included in the updated answer.  Could you be more specific on the section needed in the settings file? Quite large.