# ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery

I'm trying to learn Celery i'm using Django 2.0 and celery 5.0.2 and my os is Ubuntu.

This is my structure
My project structure is:

```
celery/
  manage.py
  celery/
    __init__.py
    cerely_app.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  apps/
      main/ 
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        task.py
        views.py
        test.py
```

My configuration for cerely_app, based on documentation:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'celery.settings')

app = Celery('celery')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

And my **init**.py:

```
from .celery_app import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

But when django give a error of import when i use command python3 manage.py runserver:

```
$python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/brayan/Envs/celery/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/brayan/Envs/celery/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/brayan/Envs/celery/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/brayan/Envs/celery/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/brayan/Envs/celery/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/brayan/dev/python/celery/celery/celery/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .celery_app import app as celery_app
  File "/home/brayan/dev/python/celery/celery/celery/celery_app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/brayan/dev/python/celery/celery/celery/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please *don't* name the module celery. it will now import your local `celery` module instead of the package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not put same name of your package and system package as it creates confusion for python when you hit import statement. In your case you name your package **celery** which is also a name of original **celery** package. In short simply rename your celery folder to something else.

Comment: Ohhh i got it, i thought many things but i never thought it will be the name of my package, thanks dude, today i learned something new, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

I recently upgraded from Python 3.6 to **Python 3.7** and I am using **Celery 4.4.6** and **Django 2.2.x** and it also gave me a similar error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'
```

However, as I had my project setup as told in the [docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.4.6/django/first-steps-with-django.html) it was referring to the right package. Only after some lost hours I stumbled accross this [Issue](https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/issues/411) here. I then fixed

```
importlib-metadata==4.8.3
```

and the problem was resolved. According to GitHub all versions < 5 might resolve the issue. Apparently Celery uses an interface from this package on specific Python versions, which they deprecated in version 5.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. Had the same issue while upgrading python version and celery version.